# Command-Line Arguments in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a problem in `NetBeans` with Command-Line Arguments, when run this code it says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Note I put an argument in command line for NetBeans

```
public class NewEmpty1
{
  public static void main(String arg[]){
   System.out.println(arg[0]);
  }
}
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: i guess you are compiling and running the program by invoking another class main method...

Comment: No , I am sure from compiling and running by invking class main method which I have put an argument to it

Answer (score 1):

goto Project-Property-Run here you will see the option 
main class
arguments

now make sure you are accessing the correct main class....after this option you have button to browse the class path. select it and then select the arguments finally you should be able to run the program...cheers!

Ashish

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed any arguments..

And if you have passed arguments then it may be because you are invoking another class **main** method in the same package

---

the best way would be to iterate..

```
for(string s:arg)
     System.out.println(s);
```

**or**

```
for(int i=0;i<arg.length();i++)
    System.out.println(arg[i]);
```

Comment: but I put an  argument in project properties

Comment: @user1841718 do your program have multiple main methods in different class..it may be because you are executing through a different class main method..i.e you may be passing arguments to another main method

Comment: yes , it have many main method but I am sure from selecting the class main method which I have put an argument to it

Answer (score 0):

```
subscript the string beyond its index is undefined.
```

this is your case. `args[]` is empty.

check this [How to pass cmd line argument](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.in/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NewMain {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int argslen=args.length;
        int argsValue[] = new int[argslen];
        for (String i:args) {
           int d = 0;
           argsValue[d]=Integer.parseInt(i);
           System.out.print(argsValue[d]+"\t"+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```